# cdkDragHandle in angular material mat-table has no effect

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to know if it is possible to have a cell that contains a mat-icon defined as

cdkDragHandle.At the moment it is active on the full row but I just want the single icon to be used as draghandle

This is part of the code I'm using:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" 
cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="dataSource"
(cdkDropListDropped)="dropTable($event)">

<ng-container matColumnDef="Order">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    Actions
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <mat-icon class="dragCursor" cdkDragHandle>reorder</mat-icon>
    {{element.order}}
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="onDeleteClick(element)">
      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

... more column definitions

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" cdkDrag    [cdkDragData]="row" cdkDragLockAxis="y"></mat-row>
```

I also tried to define the draghandle on the mat-cell to no avail.
Does anybody know how this can be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15):

It seems that `cdkDragHandle` doesn't work for `mat-table`.

Tested with latest Angular Material version, v. **9.1.0**.

This bug was also discussed on Github, where I've found the following solution:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13770#issuecomment-506182564 - author `ajp76054`.

I've used it in my project and it seems to work ok.

I'll post it here for those who will need it:

---

Initialize the table with `cdkDragDisabled` property set to `true`, in order to  disable the whole drag container. This allows the user to still interact with the table cells until they are ready to drag the row.

Then on the drag handle element (`<mat-icon>`), use `(mousedown)` event to set the `cdkDragDisabled` to `false`.
Then, reset it to `true` inside the `(cdkDropListDropped)` event handler.

So, in the template use the following code:

```html
<mat-table 
   #table 
   [dataSource]="dataSource" 
   cdkDropList 
   (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" 
   cdkDropListData="dataSource" 
   [cdkDropListDisabled]="dragDisabled">

 ...

 <ng-container matColumnDef="order">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Order</mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
    <mat-icon class="dragCursor" (mousedown)="dragDisabled = false;">reorder</mat-icon>
   </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>

 ...

 <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="row"></mat-row>


</mat-table>
```

And in component `ts` file:

```js
export class TableBasicExample {
  dragDisabled = true;
 
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
    // Return the drag container to disabled.
    this.dragDisabled = true;

    // other code on drop event
    // 
    const previousIndex = this.dataSource.findIndex((d) => d === event.item.data);

    moveItemInArray(this.dataSource, previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
this.table.renderRows();
  }

}
```

***Working example***

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materials-table-with-drag-and-drop-nvyyy4

---

**Update 2022-05-16**

Still an issue in Angular Material v13.

Working example with `@angular/cdk` & `@angular/material` - `v13.3.7` (also contains the improvement suggested by @Max Leske):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gof2zv

Comment: Even though the GitHub issue claims that this has been fixed I still needed to use your workaround (this is with @angular/cdk 11.0.3). One small improvement: use `(mouseUp)="dragDisabled = true;"` on the same element to prevent simple clicks from enabling dragging for the entire row.